# Why does BufReader not actualy buffer over short seeks?

Tags: rust

My application uses a very big file and performs many very small reads from various offsets inside a small window. I replaced my direct file reads with reads through a `BufReader`. Then I checked with Process Monitor (from Sysinternals suite) what actual reads are performed by the OS and it seems nothing gets buffered at all. Even worse it reads now the whole buffer capacity everytime which makes the performance way worse.

Reproduce:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, Read, Seek, SeekFrom};

fn main() {
    let path = "data.bin";
    let f = File::open(path).unwrap();
    let mut r = BufReader::with_capacity(8 * 1024, f);

    let mut buf = [0; 8];

    r.seek(SeekFrom::Start(0)).unwrap();
    r.read(&mut buf).unwrap();

    r.seek(SeekFrom::Start(100)).unwrap();
    r.read(&mut buf).unwrap();

    r.seek(SeekFrom::Start(200)).unwrap();
    r.read(&mut buf).unwrap();
}
```

[image]

How should I use `BufReader` in a scenario like this?

Comment: You shouldn't. `BufReader` is predicated on the idea that most reads are sequential, if your particular use case is different then you should use direct reads instead (files are not buffered by default precisely to make that possible).

Comment: It can be beneficial as working directly with a `Read` instance can be inefficient. However, it may not buffer as expected due to the `seek` function, which discards the buffer and performs a new read operation. This happens because `BufReader` cannot predict the contents of the file after a seek operation. If you're performing many small reads from various offsets, you might need to implement your own buffering strategy.

Comment: @WiseChimpanzee If the seek is withing the buffer capacity I expected it to work as it can predict the contents inside its own buffer. If the seek is outside the buffer capacity its OK to discard the buffer.

Comment: Your expectation is spot on. Buffers, like `BufReader`, are smart when you read data within their capacity. They predict and serve it swiftly, which boosts performance.

When you seek beyond the buffer's limit, it's okay for the buffer to clear and fetch fresh data from the source. This way, it keeps the data current.

Buffers, in a nutshell, aim to make reading and handling data smooth. But remember, their exact behavior may vary based on the buffer and programming language you're using. Always check the docs or code to know how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called out by the implementation of `Seek::seek` for [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#impl-Seek-for-BufReader%3CR%3E):

> Seek to an offset, in bytes, in the underlying reader.
>
> The position used for seeking with `SeekFrom::Current(_)` is the
> position the underlying reader would be at if the `BufReader<R>` had no
> internal buffer.
>
> Seeking always discards the internal buffer, even if the seek position
> would otherwise fall within it. This guarantees that calling
> `BufReader::into_inner()` immediately after a seek yields the underlying
> reader at the same position.
>
> To seek without discarding the internal buffer, use
> `BufReader::seek_relative`.
>
> See `std::io::Seek` for more details.
>
> Note: In the edge case where you’re seeking with `SeekFrom::Current(n)`
> where n minus the internal buffer length overflows an i64, two seeks
> will be performed instead of one. If the second seek returns Err, the
> underlying reader will be left at the same position it would have if
> you called seek with `SeekFrom::Current(0)`.

The reasoning is laid out, and the work-around for your usecase is provided... specifically, call `BufReader::seek_relative` instead:

> Seeks relative to the current position. If the new position lies within the buffer, the buffer will not be flushed, allowing for more efficient seeks. This method does not return the location of the underlying reader, so the caller must track this information themselves if it is required.